# Putting multiple JS scripts 1 one JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm putting multiple 2 JS scripts in 1 file, and although they worked well independently when wrapped around the  when in html file, the 2nd one simply doesn't work when I calls them from an outside JS file.

Here's the JS code:

```
// start of open the name div

$(function() {
    $('.reply_submit_name_open').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.reply_submit_name').fadeIn();
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });

    $('.check_author').click(function(){
        if($('.check_author').is(":checked")) {
            $('.name_input').val($(this).val());
            $('.name_input').attr('readonly', true);
        } else {
            $('.name_input').attr('readonly', false);
        }
    });
}); 

// end of opening name div


// start of posting replies
var base_url = '<?php print base_url();?>';
var interview_id = '<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3)?>';

$(function() {
    $('.reply_button').click(function(){

        var this_a = $(this);
        var reply = $(this).parents().siblings('textarea').val();
        var username =$(this).siblings().find('input').val();
        var parent_comment_id=$(this).closest('form').attr('id');
        var last_reply_id=$(this).closest('.reply_form_div').siblings('.replies').children().last('.comment').attr('id');

        $.ajax({ 
            type:"POST", 
            url: base_url + "comment_upload/reply_upload",
            data:{parent_comment_id : parent_comment_id, interview_id: interview_id, reply:reply, username: username}, 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data,status){
                if(data.state == 'succ') {
                    this_a.html('Success');
                    $('.reply_button').closest('.reply_form_div').siblings('.replies').append(data.new_reply);
                } else {
                    this_a.html('Bad');  
                }
            }
        });
    }); 
}); 
// end of posting replies
```

What's the cause? Appreciate any advice.

Comment: I don't see any reason they should conflict. How are you "calling them"? There are no named functions to call.

Comment: Is this in a PHP class? Because you're calling `$this`. Is the output of the JS and PHP valid?

Comment: I'm calling them based onthe button that's being clicked.

Comment: $(this) is called as in JQuery

Answer (score 0):

You've got a bunch of PHP in there that certainly won't be evaluated if you move this to an external .js file, unless you've configured your server to run all .js files through php.

Comment: I think you're right. Is there a way I can somehow pass these variables fro mthe html to the external JS?

Comment: They're globals, you only need to put the two `<?php ?>` lines into the PHP file and they'll be available to all subsequently included JavaScript.